# HTML and CSS doesn't update online due to browser caching

Tags: html, css, caching, browser

I run a website for a small company. The websites mostly contains text and images. Whenever i update the website by replacing a image or updating the css, it doesn't get updated on other people's browsers because it's been cached. I've found a way to get around this by adding a version number where i'm linking my stylesheet, however, this doesn't apply to images. What is the most simple way to get around this?

I've done a lot of research on the web and on stackoverflow, but they are all complicated solutions. There must be a better way.

Just to be clear, i know i can clear the cache in my browser. I'm looking for a solution that works for everyone who access my website.

Comment: don't cache image, disable it to force a reload each time

Comment: We write the year 2013 ... https://css-tricks.com/can-we-prevent-css-caching/

Answer (score 3):

You can add these meta tags and it will force a page to reload from the server on every reload. However, you should realize that this could result in a lot more data usage for both you and your users.

```
<meta http-equiv=“Pragma” content=”no-cache”>
<meta http-equiv=“Expires” content=”-1″>
<meta http-equiv=“CACHE-CONTROL” content=”NO-CACHE”>
```

If you have a reload link or button on your html page, you can add this attribute to it to force a reload from the server. The 'true' parameter is what forces a full reload instead of a cache reload.

```
onClick="location.reload(true);"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rename your images (preferably) automatically when you want to avoid them being cached, adding a version number to their name. If you have something which does this automatically, then you bypass the problem of caching them.

If you want to keep the name of your images, then you can make the change only temporary.

Answer (score 0):

Try versioning(`?version`) to the files to avoid browser caching.

it will be like `filename.jpg?v1` `filename.jpg?v2`

Or if you are replacing files frequently try adding current timestamp for every page load

In php,

`filename.jpg?<?= time()?>"`

where `time()` is current timestamp

This means you are just changing the urls everytime.